# How to use a Silverlight Solution

Tags: silverlight

I have a Silverlight app made in Visual Studio 2010 and I want to put it on a website but I don't have the slightest clue how.

I've looked at all the msdn documentation and they all mention a .xap file that is the file you use on the website but there is no .xap and I can't find out how to compile my code into a .xap file.

Also, when I run the App and look at the source in the browser, it has my code compiled into the .xap file, but there is no .xap file!

So my question is simply how do you go about getting a Silverlight app on a website because I've been trying for hours and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample html or aspx page is included when you create the solution. This is the page that the browser navigates to when you hit F5. You can take that page as a basic example of how to embed a Silverlight app in a page. You should find it in the project folder.

Silverlight projects are commonly built into a XAP file when you hit "Build" in VS. This file lives in the bin/Release or bin/Debug folder and basically contains your whole application.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to create a silverlight application Hosted in a web site,

1. Select Silverlight Application Template while adding new project in VS2010
2. When you click Ok, ensure that **Host the Silverlight application in a new web site** is Checked.(It will create a new ASP.Net web application to host the Silverlight)

If you haven't checked the **Host the Silverlight application in a new web site** option, you can add a new ASP.Net Web application project and then go to its properties and select **Silverlight Applications option** in left pane. Then Click **Add**, select your Silverlight Application to be hosted and click ok. You are done now.

But If haven't selected the Silverlight Application Template, then you might have created a Silverlight Class Library. It wont generate any xap file. It just gives a dll. So you need to recreate a project as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in Silverlight whenever you create a project, right at the beginning, it will ask you if you want to create a web app automatically. If you chose yes, something like YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.web will be created, go into that folder, you will find a folder called ClientBin.

The .xap file will be inside that folder.

HTH